# Rails: How to avoid drawn out urls with nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've noticed that doubly nested urls have nasty urls. Is there a way to "prettify" these without changing the model relationships? Or is it cleaner to change model relationships. Say comments-->answers-->questions and change how they interact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own routes in the routes.rb file and have them point to whatever you want.

Comment: No problem! Jeremy Baker's post has a great link to an awesome routing guide.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a read through the Rails Routing guide. It will give you all of the information you need to create beautiful custom URLs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html